# how to create animations with 3 container

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a simple animation.
When I click one of this elements, the selected item must grow larger maybe with an animation, and the others they will have to decrease.

[image]

I use a **GestureDetector()**

```
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () => {},
                              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                Image(
                                  image: AssetImage('images/one.png'),
                                  height: 80,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "One",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: kBlueColor,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ]),
                            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5BDKI7R6ag&list=PLIkXu-jDw-uXQx2cVdjuVsA5-YNrwH-8_&index=6) tutorial on animation.
You are going to want to create an animation controller. The animation controller will let you play an animation. You will also want to use the transform widget. This will allow the picture that you are using to expand or move when the animation controller is activated. Also check out [this](https://youtu.be/FCyoHclCqc8) tutorial. It's from flutter Europe and it goes in depth on animations.

Comment: don't you have a more precise example?